# About the pronunciation tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, ambiguous-tags, retagging

We have several tags relating to pronunciation. Some can be distinguished as follows:

- [readings](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readings): how the orthography is mapped onto phonemes
- [phonology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology): rules about phonemes of the language (e.g. phonotactics)
- [phonetics](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonetics): rules about how the phones of the language are actually pronounced, and how phonemes are mapped to phones

But we also have a [pronunciation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) tag, which seems to be quite general. What its purpose, and do we need it? Should we synonymize it?

If we get rid of it, we must also remove it from the example tags (shown when the "Tags" field is empty when asking a question).

Comment: My guess is it's applied by people who aren't sure which of the other three tags to use.  Not everyone would easily discover the first three or understand a lot about the differences.  A synonym would only work if everyone was consistently applying pronunciation in lieu of one tag, or else it'll trigger an endless retagging project as the synonym gets mapped to the wrong subtag and someone has to fix it.